# A cross product identity?

Tags: cross-product

In $\Bbb R^3$ if $A \times B = C$ and $B \times C = A$.

In what circunstances we can say that $A \times C = B$ ? Is it the only possibility? Why (or why not?)

Intuitively (geometrically) I think that the equation holds, but I also think that this is not true, rigorously speaking.

Comment: $$A\times C=(B\times C)\times C=(B\cdot C)C-(C\cdot C)B=-|C|^2B$$.

Comment: can you, please, elaborate on why $B \cdot C = 0$?